# Mysql order by and group error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

How can I order by to this query?

I have a problem when I try to add orderby to sql query.

The original query is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `client_data`.userid,users.username as name, 
    users.guid, `client_data`.fname, 
    `client_data`.country,`client_data`.city, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`client_data`.startdate, '%d-%m-%Y') as startdate, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`client_data`.enddate, '%d-%m-%Y') as enddate, `client_data`.registerdate, 
    `client_data`.agents, `client_data`.phone1, `client_data`.phone2, `client_data`.email, 
    `client_data`.officeName, `client_data`.address, 
    users.password, `client_data`.private, 
    users.`machineid` 
FROM `client_data` 
join users 
    on (users.iid=`client_data`.userid) 
GROUP BY `client_data`.userid 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

And I add " ORDER BY 'client_data'.userid" to query, then it not work. The new query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `client_data`.userid,users.username as name, users.guid, 
    `client_data`.fname, `client_data`.country,`client_data`.city,
    DATE_FORMAT(`client_data`.startdate, '%d-%m-%Y') as startdate, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`client_data`.enddate, '%d-%m-%Y') as enddate, 
    `client_data`.registerdate, `client_data`.agents, `client_data`.phone1, `client_data`.phone2,
    `client_data`.email, `client_data`.officeName, 
    `client_data`.address, users.password, 
    `client_data`.private, users.`machineid` 
FROM `client_data` 
join users 
    on (users.iid=`client_data`.userid) 
GROUP BY `client_data`.userid 
LIMIT 0, 25 
ORDER BY 'client_data'.userid
```

I get this error code:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ORDER BY 'client_data'.userid' at line 5Failed running

How can I add the order by

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL, LIMIT comes after the ORDER BY clause, so change:

```
GROUP BY `client_data`.userid LIMIT 0, 25 ORDER BY 'client_data'.userid
```

To:

```
GROUP BY `client_data`.userid ORDER BY `client_data`.userid LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: Additionally, `ORDER BY 'client_data'.userid` should be `ORDER BY \`client_data\`.userid` - the table name should be quoted with backticks (or not at all), not single quotes.

Comment: Nice catch, updated answer to match the group by with backticks.